# How can I get rid of unnecessary columns in powershell query output

Tags: powershell

I have this code below, when I run it the output file has additional columns like Comment, RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray,    HasErrors

```
$dataSet.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows |
ConvertTo-HTML -head $a –body $body |
Out-File $OutputFile
```

I want to get rid of these columns but dont know how to. I have checked other online resources but couldn't help. Is there anything am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude the columns you don't want with -ExcludeProperty:

```
$dataSet.Tables | 
Select-Object -Expand Rows |
Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Comment, RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors |
ConvertTo-HTML -head $a –body $body |
Out-File $OutputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off to just include the properties you want than exclude the once you don't want:

```
$dataSet.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows | Select-Object Colum1, Colum2 |
ConvertTo-HTML -head $a –body $body | Out-File $OutputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-Property` parameter works for me

```
$dataSet.Tables | Select-Object -Expand Rows |
ConvertTo-HTML -head $a –body $body -Property Name,Date,Address |
Out-File $OutputFile
```